# On Error Go To in a Loop

Tags: vba, loops, onerror

I am trying to create a loop that will look through a list of customers, and if there is a report for that customer, email that customer the report.

What I need is an On Error statement that will allow customers without reports to be skipped and allow the script to continue onto the next customer right up until the end of the customer list.

The On Error statement I have currently, gets stuck after all customers have been cycled through, and continues looping in the On Error statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
sub test()

a = 2

Check:

  Do Until UniqueBuyer.Range("A" & a).Value = ""

 On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

    Sheets(UniqueBuyer.Range("A" & a).Value).Activate

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        FolderLocation & FolderName & "\" & _
        UniqueBuyer.Range("A" & a).Value & ".pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=Flase, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        PDFFile = FolderLocation & FolderName & "\" & _
        UniqueBuyer.Range("A" & a).Value & ".pdf"

            Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutlookMail = OutLookApp.createItem(0)
            CombinedEmail = ""
            'Clear variable - LK
            On Error Resume Next
            'Display email and specify To, Subject, etc
            With OutlookMail

                .Display
                c = 4
                Do Until UniqueBuyer.Cells(a, c).Value = ""
                AdditionalEmail = UniqueBuyer.Cells(a, c)
                CombinedEmail = CombinedEmail & ";" & AdditionalEmail
                .to = CombinedEmail
                c = c + 1
                Loop

                .cc = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Weekly Wooltrade Summary " & Left(Master.Range("X2"), 3)
                .Body = ""
                .Attachments.Add PDFFile
                '.Send

             End With

            On Error GoTo 0

a = a + 1

Loop
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:

a = a + 1
GoTo Check

 End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use `GoTo` to exit a error handler. Use `Resume Check` instead of `GoTo Check`. And the `Check` label should probably be inside the loop, not outside. Maybe just before the `a = a+1` line.

Comment: Thanks @VincentG! 
Would putting Check Label just after the a=a+1 line and before the Loop line be better?
So that a doesn't jump from a=2 to a=4 for example?

Comment: Put it before a=a+1 and remove the same line from the handler is the best choice, imho, but I haven't got into details of your code.

Comment: Thanks @VincentG That's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

the `On Error GoTo` way is hardly the one to go: you'd better check for any possible error and handle it

furthermore you'd also better instantiate one Outlook Application only for all needed emails

finally there were some typos (`Flase` -> `False`)

here's a possible (commented) refactoring of your code for what above:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim UniqueBuyer As Worksheet, Master As Worksheet
    Dim FolderLocation As String, FolderName As String, PDFFile As String
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    FolderLocation = "C:\Users\...\" '<--| change it to your actual folder location
    FolderName = "Test" '<--| change it to your actual folder name

    Set UniqueBuyer = Worksheets("UniqueBuyer") '<--| change "UniqueBuyer" to your actual Unique Buyer sheet name
    Set Master = Worksheets("Master") '<--| change "Master" to your actual Master sheet name

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") '<--| set one Outlook application outside the loop

    With UniqueBuyer '<--| reference your "Unique Buyer" sheet
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through its column A cells with constant (i.e. not from formulas) text content from row 2 down to last not empty one
            PDFFile = FolderLocation & FolderName & "\" & cell.Value & ".pdf" '<--| build your PDF file name
            With .Range(cell.Offset(, 3), cell.Offset(, 3).End(xlToRight)) '<--| reference current buyer cells from column 4 rightwards
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) > 0 Then '<--| if any not-blank cells in referenced ones
                    If OKSheetAndExportToPDF(cell.Value, PDFFile) Then '<--| if successfully found current buyer sheet and exported it to PDF
                        'Display email and specify To, Subject, etc
                        With OutLookApp.createItem(0) '<--| create a new mail item and reference it
                            .Display
                            .to = GetCombinedEmails(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)) '<--| get emails string from currently referenced cells with some constant text value
                            .cc = ""
                            .BCC = ""
                            .Subject = "Weekly Wooltrade Summary " & Left(Master.Range("X2"), 3)
                            .Body = ""
                            .Attachments.Add PDFFile
                            '.Send
                        End With
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With

    Set OutLookApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCombinedEmails(rng As Range) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    With rng
        If .Count = 1 Then
            GetCombinedEmails = .Value
        Else
            GetCombinedEmails = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Value)), ";") '<--| join all found consecutive email addresses in one string
        End If
    End With
End Function

Function OKSheetAndExportToPDF(shtName As String, PDFFile As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ExitFunction
    With Worksheets(shtName)
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=PDFFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=False
        OKSheetAndExportToPDF = True
    End With
ExitFunction:
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @user3598756 !

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your question then please mark it as accepted. Thank you!